# Does "chromatography" have plural (chromatographies)?

Tags: grammatical-number, uncountable-nouns, countable-nouns

Chromatography is a chemical method which can be performed in different ways. Some of main types are liquid chromatography, gas chromatography, size exclusion chromatography. Oxford dictionary classifies this word as a mass noun. Merriam-Webster dictionary and some scientific papers contain "chromatographies".

Comment: On Google Books  you can find a few usage instances: https://www.google.com/search?q=%22chromatographies%22&tbm=bks&lr=lang_en

Comment: Chomatography (countable and uncountable, plural chromatographies). Wiktionary https://en.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/chromatography

Comment: A [Google Scholar](https://scholar.google.com/scholar?start=10&q=Chromatographies&hl=en&as_sdt=0,34) search shows *chromatographies* has long been common in the sciences.

Comment: Is there a reason that you don't believe it has a plural? Otherwise you seem to be saying "I found it in dictionaries and papers. Is it real?" to which the answer is obvious.